# Why does my compose key not work after a reinstall?

Tags: linux-mint, compose-key

mapped Alt Gr to Compose. If I use Alt Gr in combination with another key, then it behaves like a modifier, like Shift or Ctrl, but if I press it and release it, then it behaves like a Compose key. I could press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, then <kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>e</kbd>, to get `æ` for example.

At least, that's how it used to work. Now, I have re-installed Linux Mint, and though the configuration didn't change, the behaviour did. xev still reveals that <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> is keycode 108.

This line

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Multi_key"
```

still gets executed when I log in. But the key does nothing! What has happened?

Thinking this was a subtle change to do how a keysym can be mapped to a modifier key, I tried

```
xmodmap -n -e "keycode 94 = Multi_key"
```

which is the backslash key to the left of <kbd>Z</kbd>. Alas, that doesn't do anything either.

Have I even got the right xmodmap installed?

```
$ sudo apt-get install xmodmap
[sudo] password for you: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xmodmap is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  x11-xserver-utils:i386 x11-xserver-utils

E: Package 'xmodmap' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not install xmodmap. The output of your `sudo apt-get install xmodmap` tells you that `Package xmodmap is not available`, and says that it is replaced with `x11-xserver-utils`. Install `x11-xserver-utils` and then run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your quotes! I had the same issue and only replacing the double quotes with single quotes made it work. I checked again and it turned out that at some stage the line from my script got stored as
`/usr/bin/xmodmap -e “keycode 91 = 0xffac period”`
that doesn't work, however
`/usr/bin/xmodmap -e "keycode 91 = 0xffac period"`
does